# Bash string to date wrong value

Tags: linux, string, bash, date

I have the following lines in a bash script:

```
TIME_START="20:00";

TIME_OLD_STRING=`date +%y%m%d`S`date --date=${TIME_START} +%H:%M`
echo ${TIME_OLD_STRING}
TIME_OLD_DATE=`date -d ${TIME_OLD_STRING} +%y%m%dS%H:%M`
echo ${TIME_OLD_DATE}
```

The purpose is to transform a string of the form `HH:MM` into a date of the form `current_date HH:MM`.

My problem is that for the lines above i get the following echoed output:

```
130820S20:00
130820S17:00
```

The current date is 20 August 2013, but the hour is not the expected one,
therefore the conversion is wrong. I am expecting the second output to be also
    `130820S20:00`

What have i done wrong and how do i correct it? Or at least which way do i go from here.

Comment: The output 130820 is 20 August 2013. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your output, the date is correct. It does exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: why don't you just use date "+%y%m%d $TIME_START"? That's a single command that fulfils your needs (unless I missed something). It would be helpful if you could tell the exact output you'd expect for the given input.

Comment: Am i expecting wrong that the hour should be 20:00, not 17:00? Edited the question.

Comment: Did you check that it isn't a problem with the timezone? That it somehow assumes you use UTC and therefore the time has a strange diff?

Comment: i am checking right now. Since i am in GMT +3, i think the problem might be related to the timezone

Answer (score 1):

The second date command doesn't interpret `TIME_OLD_STRING` correctly. Only the date part of it was understood, so it uses current time instead.

From the date(1) man page:

> The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or even "next Thursday".  A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning of the day.  The date string format is more  complex  than is easily documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.

If you need the same output twice (this is how it looks like in your example), just add another

```
echo ${TIME_OLD_STRING}
```

Otherwise, what exactly should the second date command do?

Comment: It always prints the time with 3 hours before the hour given. If it is `05:00` the second one prints `02:00`. I do not print the dates in the script. I plan on using the second one later on. It was echoed just to show the problem i have.

Comment: Ok, it seems the "S" in TIME_OLD_STRING is the problem. As I wrote, the given timestring cannot be interpreted correctly. But you still didn't tell us, what your real needs are. If you want the same date string assigned to two variables, you don't have to use another date command.

Comment: i plan to search for files with regard to their modification, data modification time. But now i get what you told me in the comment. I erased the second date command and it works.

Comment: So my answer was correct, but wasn't what you were actually searching for. Please consider accepting or upvoting the answer and/or comments.